# scala DynamicVariable and play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to use a DynamicVariable with scala Play 2.5 framework to propagate a context per request. So far my DynamicVariable works perfectly in the request thread, but doesn't get copied over when using a Future and play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext. How can I copy the value of my DynamicVariable so that it is available within my Future when using play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext. Most of my work is based on the following article.

http://stevenskelton.ca/threadlocal-variables-scala-futures/

So to recap, my DynamicVariable works when I use
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global and Futures
but not when I use
implicit val executionContext = play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext and Futures

Can someone help me?

Thanking you in advance
Francis